# Unwanted spacing between Containers inside Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column widget with two Containers widgets inside it. Both the container widgets have two listview builders. First listview builder scross horizontally and the second scrolls vertically. The issue I am facing is with the second container carrying the vertical listview builder. There is a lot of unwanted space betweeen the two containers. I have not added any margin or spacing between them. So I cant figure out where this space is coming from.

[image]

Here is what the code looks like: This widget holds the Vertical List which holds the horizontal list inside it

```
class _HomeDataState extends State<HomeData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final userData = Provider.of<UserData>(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          VerticalList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerticalList extends StatelessWidget {
  //const VerticalList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          height: 188,
          child: HorizontalList(),
        ),
        Container(
          //color: Colors.amber,
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return VerticalTile();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  //const HorizontalList({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          bool first = index == 0;
          return HorizontalTile(first: first);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerticalTile extends StatelessWidget {
  //const VerticalTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 465,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: const Color(0xffF9F9ED),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0xff131200).withOpacity(0.20),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Text('Container'),
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool first;
  //const HorizontalTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  HorizontalTile({this.first});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 168,
      width: 122,
      margin: first
          ? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 23, 0, 23)
          : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 23, 0, 23),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xffF9F9ED),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0xff131200).withOpacity(0.20),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Text('Container'),
    );
  }
}
```

My aim is to remove this spacing as I want to be able to define my own spacing between them.

[Edited]

I have added a color to the container that has this spacing. However, there is no spacing added to this container.

[image]

Updated code:

```
class VerticalList extends StatelessWidget {
  //const VerticalList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          height: 188,
          child: HorizontalList(),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber, //Added the color here
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return VerticalTile();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here is how the widgets look in devtools
[image]

Comment: One way to figure out where this space is coming from: If you open the Flutter DevTools, you can enable debug paint. This will show which of the 2 views causes this space

Comment: I have added a color to the container to display where the spacing is coming from. I have added the code and image as well

Comment: Can you try this refactored code and let me know: https://gist.github.com/omishah/adfac5389f697cfe9d31367a8b6a13ce

Comment: gist.github.com/omishah/adfac5389f697cfe9d31367a8b6a13ce - Tried this, still get the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add zero padding to your listview builder. in IoS platforms there is default padding, but not in Android platform.

```
   ListView.builder(
        
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        ///your code
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I have been cracking my head on this for the longest time. That solved the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to wrap them on Expanded or Flexible widget? on Containers

Comment: Yes when i replace the container with an Expanded widget, i get an error thrown stating render box was not laid out

I/flutter (10149): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#3bd63 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (10149): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#fb0af NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE